# (S)FTP with Inbox Outbox

Tags: ftp, sftp

I’ve been tasked with setting up FTP access so a client can download files we upload from an Inbox folder and they can send to us by uploading to Outbox. Personally, I’d rather just create an FTP account and allow files to get put wherever, but from what I gather, Inbox/Outbox may be better?

Whilst I’ve seen this before in action, I’m unsure how I could set this up exactly, aside from simply creating 2 folders...

I’ve not really been able to find much info online as unsure if this setup has a technical name, if I search ftp inbox outbox, naturally I get a lot of email related results

We’ve got a CentOS WHM/cPanel account, but using the basic CHMOD permissions may not be the best way? Not sure if there’s a better module to manage this?

I believe Inbox should only allow a client to download and delete files, so no deleting or renaming or uploading, whereas Outbox they can create, update and delete? And of course no new directories can be created by the client in Outbox nor the root

Likewise, don’t really want any scripts to be allowed to run which could possibly cause issues, so what I’ve done is created a separate cPanel account using a sub domain and hosting everything outside of public_html

Any tips, hints, suggestions, would be gratefully welcomed as always

Comment: is Inbox/Outbox a proper noun? are they services or pieces of software? or are you just talking about setting up an FTP instance where people can get/download from one directory (mapped to Inbox) and put/upload to another (mapped to Outbox)? also, note, SFTP is very differant from FTP. you probably want FTPS, which is FTP over TLS, so FTPS is to FTP what HTTPS is to HTTP.

Comment: @FrankThomas I’m not sure if it is a piece of software or a service or simply how the directories are permissioned. When I’ve seen it, it was those 2 directory names only can upload to Inbox and only download (delete?) from Outbox. I should think are mapped to a system level user inbox and outbox for processing and sending back

Comment: it sounds as simple as having two folders with scripts monitoring them, such that when a file is dropped into Inbox, it gets automatically `put` to the server, and periodically, files from the server are pulled via `get`, and `delete`. FTP is perfectly script-able, so the only other trick involved is how you will monitor the hot-folder and the upload location. Could be as simple as a shell script and a cronjob, depending on the rules you want to program in.